# How to increase "tracking speed" beyond the maximum?

Tags: mac, macbook-pro, preferences, trackpad

For a Macbook Pro, I've set trackpad settings for **Three Fingers** to "Dragging":

[image]

However the tracking speed is too slow, and often it's impossible to drag for a larger distance due to the size of the physical trackpad.

How do we increase the tracking speed beyond the maximum allowed?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/) does that, and lets you add application specific gestures as well!

In BetterTouchTool, open Preferences. In the left bar under Advanced Settings choose either Trackpad or Magic Mouse. There is a slider that adjusts the tracking speed.

I don't think I could use a mac without it, at this point. I have my browser-tab-management and finder shortcuts mapped to multitouch gestures.

Comment: It is under `Basic Settings` > `Magic Mouse` > `Set mouse speed`.  It is amazing!

Comment: Perfect, perfect tool. Like you, I can't use my mac without it. Thanks :). Love it

Comment: FYI, BetterTouchTool does not work in Sierra for this purpose (BTT now has a warning next to this option).  The answer from @user495470 worked for me - "defaults write -g com.apple.trackpad.scaling -float 5.0" (or for mouse: "defaults write -g com.apple.mouse.scaling -float 5.0").

Comment: @LukeWilliams - Apple seems dead-set on ruining Mac OS. Bring back snow leopard!

Comment: no longer valid

Comment: moved here: https://folivora.ai

Comment: Not free Nowadays

Comment: $22 just to change mouse speed? Seriously?

Answer (score 88):

The value of the preference is stored in `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist` and can be changed with something like `defaults write -g com.apple.trackpad.scaling -float 5.0`. The normal maximum value is currently `3.0`. Applying the changes requires logging out and back in.

Comment: For those who come here searching for mouse speed up (as me) change the above command/property to `com.apple.mouse.scaling`. So `defaults write -g com.apple.mouse.scaling -float 5.0` is what you're looking for.

Comment: I found the file but how did you guys read the content of the file? It contains strange strings.

Comment: @Lucas Would you mind putting your comment as an answer? That way your information isn't lost if your comment is accidentally removed. I came here looking for a way to increase mouse speed and I'm sure others have too. I'll upvote you!

Comment: @Dr_Hope You're not actually supposed to open the file, but you can modify it using the command mentioned in the answer. Open your **Terminal** app and enter this command: `defaults write -g com.apple.trackpad.scaling -float 5.0`

Comment: the value 5.0 isn't speeding up my macbook pro trackpad. 3.0 seems to be the maximum, any greater value have no speed gain. I'm curious to know if BetterTouchTool can actually make the internal trackpad move faster. If it can, there must be another terminal command that can do it too.

Answer (score 59):

For those who come here searching for mouse speed up (as me), change the command/property mentioned on the [answer of @user495470](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/15487/241771) to `com.apple.mouse.scaling`.

So:

```
defaults write -g com.apple.mouse.scaling -float 5.0
```

is what you're looking for.

*Here is  @Kodos Johnson :)*

Comment: And be sure to logout or reboot for it to take effect.

Comment: `defaults read -g com.apple.mouse.scaling` was helpful for me to see first that mine is set at 3`. Unfortunately neither `defaults write -g com.apple.mouse.scaling -float 5.0` nor `defaults write -g com.apple.mouse.scaling -float 7.0` seemed to have any effect, even logging out and back in after each. So I'm still looking for a solution because the max mouse tracking speed is intolerably slow for a 42.5" monitor.

Comment: does not seem to work on Catalina, same outcome as described by @Ryan. Lucas: what version of MacOS were you using where this worked for you?

Comment: @Z4-tier Here is what worked for me: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365655/how-to-increase-mouse-tracking-speed-beyond-the-maximum-for-macos-mojave-10-14?rq=1#comment566248_365655

Comment: small caveat: this worked for my normal usb-cable-mouse, but setting tracking-speed to 5.0 made my magic mouse 2 laggy as hell.

Comment: @Ryan - 5.0 did not have an effect for me. But 10.0 worked. Be sure to log out and log back in. `defaults write -g com.apple.mouse.scaling -float 10.0`

Answer (score 6):

Mouse Curves is a preference pane that allows you to customize the tracking speed of the mouse and trackpad.

http://triq.net/mac/mouse-acceleration-preference-pane-mac-os-x

Answer (score 2):

Ordinary trackpad-dragging can be done in segments, the same way mouse-dragging can be done in limited space, by lifting & repositioning {the mouse; your fingers} and making another swipe.  In your prefpane, enable one-finger click and drag, and you won't even need to press down.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before, the file is in `~/Library/Preferences/`.

But preferences will be found in more than one file.

.GlobalPreferences.plist
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist
com.apple.AppleMultitouchMouse.plist
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist

Note that .GlobalPreferences.plist is invisible.

Mouse speed is called `scaling` in `.GlobalPreferences.plist`.

Setting `scaling` past 3 with `defaults write -g com.apple.mouse.scaling 5` has no effect immediately and may require a logout.

file://~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppleMultitouchMouse.plist
file://~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist
file://~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist

Answer (score 1):

If you turn inertial scrolling on, you can, once you've started a drag gesture, keep two fingers steady and flick with the other one to inertially "drag" the window around your screen(s).