# How to increase mouse tracking speed beyond the maximum for MacOS Mojave 10.14?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave, mouse

I have been trying to increase maximum tracking speed for my 2018 Macbook Pro trackpad past the normal settings for Mac OS Mojave 10.14, but I am unsuccessful.
 [image] 
I have looking at the previous answers, but they only apply to Mac OS High Sierra. I have tried the following commands in Terminal:

```
defaults write -g com.apple.mouse.scaling -float 5.0

defaults write -g com.apple.trackpad.scaling -float 5.0
```

It seems that the names of the files have changed so I am unable to change the correct ones.

Comment: `defaults read -g com.apple.mouse.scaling` was helpful for me to see first that mine is set at 3`. Unfortunately neither `defaults write -g com.apple.mouse.scaling -float 5.0` nor `defaults write -g com.apple.mouse.scaling -float 7.0` seemed to have any effect, even logging out and back in after each. So I'm still looking for a free solution because the max mouse tracking speed is intolerably slow for a 42.5" monitor.

Comment: This works: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/295816/macos-sierra-increase-mouse-cursor-speed-beyond-system-preferences-maximum?rq=1#comment566247_325336

Answer (score 2):

The app [SteerMouse](http://www.plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/download.php) has multiple adjustments for tracking speed and acceleration, which go beyond the limits imposed by the macOS controls. I've used it for years to resolve the same complaint. SteerMouse 5.3.8 works happily on Mojave.

Edit July 7, 2021: SteerMouse (now v. 5.5.7) continues to work correctly under macOS 11.4 Big Sur.

**NOTE:** Apple Magic Mouse and Magic Trackpad are not supported.

Comment: @user3439894 Very good, that's useful additional information.